# Define NServiceBus instance-mapping in code

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I'm writing an asp.net core application and wanna send a message to an NServiceBus endpoint.

As we have different environments I need to configure an endpoint address for each environment. I do that in the app settings.Env.json.

I like to do the same with the instance mappings. The only ways I know is to have a different `instance-mapping.xml` file for every environment or add it to the app.config that I don't have. Is there a way to set the instance machine in code? I don't wanna have different XML files.

I use NServiceBus 6.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a feature to the endpoint configuration:

```
endpointConfiguration.EnableFeature<MyFeature>();

public class MyFeature : Feature
{
    protected override void Setup(FeatureConfigurationContext context)
    {
        var endpointInstances = context.Settings.Get<EndpointInstances>();
        endpointInstances.AddOrReplaceInstances("InstanceMapping",
            new List<EndpointInstance>
            {
                new EndpointInstance("MyEndpoint").AtMachine("VM-1")
            });
    }
}
```

Check docs [here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/routing) and [here](https://docs.particular.net/transports/msmq/routing)